# Creating a struct to optimize for speed

Tags: c++, struct

A char is one byte, a short is two bytes, an int is four bytes, and a double is eight bytes.
I currently have the struct setup for memory so it looks like this:

```
struct Whatever
{
    double d;
    int b;
    short a;
    char c;
};
```

How would I change the order of variables to optimize for speed? Meaning being able to read the members of a struct as fast as possible, even if extra memory is used. Or is the best performance design the memory design?

Comment: Define what "performance" means in this context. Are you looking to minimize padding?

Comment: I think the performance gains would be absolutely negligible, unless memory access takes bajillions of CPU cycles.

Comment: Looks perfect to me... nicely ordered to minimize padding...

Comment: Profile, profile, profile.  If you don't measure, you are just guessing.

Comment: By performance I mean  optimize for speed

Comment: "optimize for speed" - Speed of "what" do we measure? You can measure an action, something that happens. A structure or order of variables just exists. Or are you asking about compilation speed? -edit  The reading speed depends on _so many_ factors it's literally impossible to answer. What architecture are you targeting? How big are the types? Assuming `sizeof(double) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(short) + sizeof(char) = 8+2+2+1 < 16` you can fit the structure into 16 bytes, which you could read with a single 128bit read instruction....

Comment: Be able to read the members of a struct as fast as possible, even if extra memory is used @KamilCuk

Comment: Since you understand the speed for performance, here is nothing to do with this structure, because it fits into the cache-line. But if you want to work with arrays you need to make it's size be a divider of your cache-line size (32 or 64 bytes).

Comment: Also if you care about memory performance you might find this talk about [data-oriented design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc) interesting.